# Toggling classes?

Tags: jquery

I have the following script which works fairly well:

```
$(".btnMinimize").live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 

    $( this ).parents( ".portlet" ).find( ".portlet-sub-header" ).toggle();
    $( this ).parents( ".portlet" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
    $( this ).parents( ".portlet" ).find( ".portlet-footer" ).toggle();
});
```

the `.btnMinimize` is within a div tag with the class `.portlet-header`.

When this button is clicked, how do I get it to toggle style sheet classes which would in-tern toggle the image of the button being clicked, so it should change from a minimize icon to a maximize icon.

Right now the button is assigned the class `.btnMinimize`, which should toggle to `.btnMaximize`, bearing in mind that the button state will be database generated, i.e. if the button for portlet 1 is minimize, and for portlet 2 is maximize, it should toggle appropriately.

I am not sure if this is the best way to go about doing this, so please feel free to suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation, evaluate the condition then select if you need to show/hide the elements. Doing that assures you of the behavior of the toggle function.

```
if ( showOrHide == true ) {
    $('#foo').show();
} else if ( showOrHide == false ) {
    $('#foo').hide();
}
```

source : http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Personnaly, I found that way of doing it more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be wanting [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
$(".btnMinimize").live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 

    $( this ).parents( ".portlet" ).toggleClass('collapse');
});
```

And some CSS:

```
.collapse .portal-sub-header,
.collapse .portal-content,
.collapse .portal-footer {
    display: none;
}
```